# The integral of dv

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the homogeneous differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x + y}{x}$$

After substituting $y = vx$ and $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = v + x\cdot \dfrac{dv}{dx}$ (Product rule of $y = vx$), we have:

$v + x\cdot \frac{dv}{dx} = 1 + v.\quad$         Cancelling gives,

$x\cdot \frac{dv}{dx} = 1.\quad$        Rearranging gives,

$$\int\,dv =\int \frac 1x\, dx$$

What is the integral of $dv$? I initially thought it was $+c$ since there is no value under the integral, but elsewhere I have seen the answer as $v + c$. I'm looking for some clarification on this.

Many thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 3):

To see why it's $v + C$, write:

$\displaystyle \int \, \mathrm dv = \int 1 \, \mathrm dv$

Comment: Edit: I see it now, cheers

Answer (score 3):

$$\int \,dv = \int (1)\,dv = v+c$$ (Recall that $\frac {d}{dv}(v) = 1)$

$$\int \,dv = \int \frac 1x\, dx \iff v = \ln|x| + C$$

Comment: You don't have to use an absolute value in $\ln $ when dealing with an indefinite integral. Although it is not wrong...

Comment: @Tolaso Sure you do, since there's nothing forbidding $x$ from being negative in the original problem statement.